# Passing a parameter to a sql query using pyodbc failing

Tags: sql, parameters, pyodbc

I have read dozens of similar posts and tried everything but I still get an error message when trying to pass a parameter to a simple query using pyodbc. Apologies if there is an answer to this elsewhere but I cannot find it

I have a very simple table:

```
select * from Test
```

yields

```
a
b
c
```

This works fine:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=HyperCube SYSTEST',autocommit=True)
result = pandas.read_sql("""select * from Test where value = 'a'""",connection,params=None)
print(result)
```

result:

```
  value
0     a
```

However if I try to do the where clause with a parameter it fails

```
result = pandas.read_sql("""select * from Test where value = ?""",connection,params='a')
```

yields

```
Error: ('01S02', '[01S02] Unknown column/parameter value (9001) (SQLPrepare)')
```

I also tried this

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select * from Test where value = ?""",['a'])
pyodbcResults = cursor.fetchall()
```

and still received the same error

Does anyone know what is going on? Could it be an issue with the database I am querying?

PS. I looked at the following post and the syntax there in the first part of answer 9 where dates are passed by strings looks identical to what I am doing

*pyodbc the sql contains 0 parameter markers but 1 parameters were supplied' 'hy000'*

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyodbc the sql contains 0 parameter markers but 1 parameters were supplied' 'hy000'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491381/pyodbc-the-sql-contains-0-parameter-markers-but-1-parameters-were-supplied-hy0)

Comment: Maybe a compatibility issue with your ODBC driver? `result = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn, params=('a',))` works for me with pyodbc 4.0.23 and ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server using `?` as the parameter placeholder (`... WHERE value = ?`). Can you test using some other database platform?

Answer (score 3):

> pandas.read_sql(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, columns=None, chunksize=None)[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html]¶
>
> params : list, tuple or dict, optional, default: None

example:

```
cursor.execute("select * from Test where value = %s",['a'])
```

or Named arguments example:

```
result = pandas.read_sql(('select * from Test where value = %(par)s'),
               db,params={"par":'p'})
```

in pyodbc write parms directly after sql parameter:

> cursor.execute(sql, *parameters)

for example:

```
onepar = 'a'
cursor.execute("select * from Test where value = ?", onepar)

cursor.execute("select a from tbl where b=? and c=?", x, y)
```

Comment: Although all of the pyodbc documentation states to use ?, I tried %s also and got a different error message that seems to indicate that %s is not a valid marker:  ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I also tried the named argument route but also received the same error: ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: read about [pyodbc - Cursor](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Cursor.wiki)

Comment: Tried your exact code above (first two lines) and get the original error - this just seems bizarre - I have tried every possible example and I can't figure it out : Error: ('01S02', '[01S02] Unknown column/parameter value (9001) (SQLPrepare)')

Comment: `con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=HyperCube SYSTEST',autocommit=True)  
cur = cnxn.cursor()  
cur.execute("""select * from Test where value = ?""", 'a')  
rows = cursor.fetchall()`